If $L$, $M$, and $N$ are the middle points of the sides $BC$, $CA$, and $AB$ of a triangle $ABC$, the lines $LM$, $LN$, $LA$, and $LB$ are harmonic.
If $L$, $M$, and $N$ are the middle points of the sides $CB$, $CA$, and $AB$ of a triangle $ABC$, then prove that the lines $LM$, $LN$, $LA$, and $LB$ are harmonic or $L${$MNAB$} $= -1$.
I know how to do this if instead of the middle points I have the heights of the triangle. But this problem is giving me particular trouble. At first I tried using Ceva but got nowhere.
Any help is appreciated

Please do not answer in the comments.

Why was my question closed? :(

Your question was closed because it is not satisfying the usual general indications for a question. To see how to ask a good question, please read: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question - It should come with an explicit clear question, that should not change in time, and provide context, for instance one or better all points in the following list: source, level, why is the question important (for the asker and/or for the community), what did you try (so that answers do not repeat things you already know, and come in the shown maturity), a picture...

And also, when a "special kind" of solution is wanted, then please specify the restrictions. Usually, dealing with cross ratios is part of the projective geometry. Just count how many times "projective" comes on the wiki page for it, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-ratio . If you tried Ceva, please type what you tried, the potential answerers will type more. For this, please try to use mathjax, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference, this is a small piece of work, we know, but MSE offers such pieces of work by intention.

We compute the cross ratio of the four lines by intersecting them with the line $MN$ (in the projective space). Then $LA$ intersects $MN$ in the mid-point $Q$ of $MN$, and $LB$ intersects $MN$ at infinity, $\infty$ in notation. We thus have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
L\{MN;AB\}
&=
L\{MN;Q\infty\}
\\
&=\operatorname{CrossRatio}\{MN;Q\infty\}
\\
&=\operatorname{CrossRatio}\{Q\infty;MN\}
\\
&=
\underbrace{\frac{QM}{QN}}_{=-1}\cdot
\underbrace{\frac{\infty M}{\infty N}}_{=+1}
=-1\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

Later EDIT: I was attentioned to include a solution not including the projective space. Here is one among many. Let $Q$ be the point making $ABCQ$ a parallelogram, so $Q$ is the reflection of $B$ w.r.t. $M$. We intersect the bundle of the given four lines with the line $BQ$. Two intersections are $B,M$. The other two are denoted by $A',N'$ as in the picture.

We use on the ray $[BQ$ a coordonate system that places $B$ in zero and $M$ in $6$. Then $A'$ is the centroid of $\Delta ABC$, it is placed at one third distance from $M$, two third from $B$. So the coordinate of $A'$ is $4$. We finally notice that $BLMN$ is also a parallelogram, so $N'$ is the mid point of $BM$, its coordinate is $3$. The wanted cross ratio is thus
$$
\frac{MA'}{N'A'}\cdot
\frac{N'B}{MB}
=
\frac{4-2}{4-3}\cdot\frac{0-3}{0-6}
=
-\frac 21\cdot\frac36=-1\ .
$$

I’m looking for a solution that doesn’t use projective space

Please mention in the text what kind of solution you want, best which solution you have (thus providing context), and why that solution is not good enough. There is a downvote for this solution, the downvoter may want to also expose the own opinion. It is possibly because the question attracted a lot of downvotes after i started typing, in this case please give me an interface that shows the downvotes while typing an answer.
